# break the loop when list len reaches to 5 (In for loop)

Tags: python, arrays, json, django, list

I am building a simple python program and I am trying to filter some response based on limit to run the for loop or while loop.

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to stop the loop when list `len` reaches to 5. It can be a for loop and while loop.

views.py

```
def filter_array(request):
   new_array = []
   count = 1
   quit = False
   
   for m in res.get("blogs"):
      for likes in m.get("likes"):
         try:
             count += 1
             if likes == "user_1":
                 new_array.append(likes)

             if count == 5:
                 quit = True
                 break
         except:
                 quit = True
                 break
   print(new_array)

   return new_array
```

json response in views.py

```
res = {
   "blogs": [
      {
         "title": "Blog 1",
         "description": "Blog description",
         "likes": [
            "user_1",
            "user_2",
         ]
      },
      {
         "title": "Blog 2",
         "description": "Blog description",
         "likes": [
            "user_4",
            "user_5",
         ]
      },
      {
         "title": "Blog 3",
         "description": "Blog description",
         "likes": [
            "user_3",
         ]
      },
      {
         "title": "Blog 4",
         "description": "Blog description",
         "likes": [
            "user_3",
            "user_4",
            "user_5",
         ]
      },
      {
         "title": "Blog 5",
         "description": "Blog description",
         "likes": [
            "user_4",
            "user_5",
         ]
      },
   ]
}
```

When I run the above code then It is appending all the json items in the array.
But I want to append in list if **"likes"** is `user_1` and stop loop when list len reaches the 5.

I have tried many hours but it is still not working.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the `try...except`. You should remove it.

Comment: Check out slices in python. You can use them to easily get the first 5 elements of a list without the need for a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but from what I understand, try this:

```py
def filter_array(request):
    new_array = []
    count = 1
    flag = False
    for m in res.get("blogs"):
        for likes in m.get("likes"):
            try:
                count += 1
                if likes == "user_1":
                    new_array.append(likes)

                if count == 5:
                    flag = True
                    break
            except:
                flag = True
                break
        if flag: # break if flag is True
            break
    print(new_array)
    return new_array
```

### Changes

1. Use `flag` instead of `quit` because `quit()` is a built-in function.
2. Added flag check in outer for-loop.

Comment: I am trying it... Just a minute

Comment: Just a random suggestion, try using black formatted. https://pypi.org/project/black/

Answer (score 1):

The `break` only breaks out of one loop. Because you have a 2nd loop nested inside of the 1st loop you need another `break`.

```py
def filter_array(request):
   new_array = []
   count = 1
   
   for m in res.get("blogs"):
      for likes in m.get("likes"):
         count += 1
         if likes == "user_1":
            new_array.append(likes)
            
         if count == 5:
            break
      if count == 5:
         break
   print(new_array)
   
   return new_array
```

Comment: On a side note, you removed the unecessary `try...except`, too. Just pointing this out for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC this is all you need:

```
res = {
    "blogs": [
      {
          "title": "Blog 1",
          "description": "Blog description",
          "likes": [
              "user_1",
              "user_2",
          ]
      },
        {
          "title": "Blog 2",
          "description": "Blog description",
          "likes": [
              "user_4",
              "user_5",
          ]
      },
        {
          "title": "Blog 3",
          "description": "Blog description",
          "likes": [
              "user_3",
          ]
      },
        {
          "title": "Blog 4",
          "description": "Blog description",
          "likes": [
              "user_3",
              "user_4",
              "user_5",
          ]
      },
        {
          "title": "Blog 5",
          "description": "Blog description",
          "likes": [
              "user_4",
              "user_5",
          ]
      },
    ]
}

new_list = []

for dict_ in res['blogs']:
    if 'user_1' in dict_.get('likes', []):
        new_list.append(dict_)
        if len(new_list) == 5:
            break

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'title': 'Blog 1', 'description': 'Blog description', 'likes': ['user_1', 'user_2']}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. What is the full form of IIUC ?

Comment: @ropox IIUC == 'If I Understand Correctly'. Does this answer do what you need? Maybe I did not understand the challenge

Comment: Thanks for the Response, and... yes it solve but everybody was suggessting for removing `try...` and `except` But I did managed to keep it and put three break statements for every loop and it worked

Comment: The only reason why you might want try/except is for the case where the 'likes' key doesn't exist but you can check for that. I'll change the code to show how that can be achieved

Comment: @ropox You should only use `try...except` when you know there is an exception that you need to handle. Since you use `get()` instead of brackets, you won't have any exceptions, so there is no need for `try...except`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first five elements of a list with a slice. Something like this:

```
def filter_array(request):
    all_likes = []
    for likes in m.get("likes", [])
        all_likes.extend(likes)
    return all_likes[:5]
```

Don't make things more complicated than you need to. For example, there is no reason for a `try...except` here.

Comment: It will take so much time on bigger array, and If I want to get only 15 results and array (json) is bigger then 150 then It will take so much time for appending and then will append with responses of no use other than 15

Comment: @ropox You are correct that this isn't very efficient bit for the extra time and extra space used. I doubt you will actually notice for only 150 items, though. I argue that this 5 line solution is easier to understand than your 20 line supplying If this is really a concern, you can add an if statement to break the for loop early. Still this will be

Comment: @ropix that is a fair point. This solution is far from the most efficient, but it is also much simpler than your attempt. And more importantly, it is correct (at least from what I can tell from your stated requirements). A slow, correct solution is much more valuable than a fast, wrong solution. With that said, you can easily add an if statement to this solution to break early. That change is easier because this solution is so short and simple. Sorry if this sounds like bragging. I don't mean it that way. My point is that generally, it is best to write simple solutions.

Comment: @ropox a note about correctness: my code will return up to the first five likes from all of the blogs in the list. This is my best interpretation of what you are trying to do. However, after a closer look at your original code, I'm not so sure this is what you actually want. If you still need help, please give me details about what you are trying to do. Your question seems to be about HOW you are solving a problem, but never explains WHAT the original problem is.